# How to run PostgreSql queries without package "database/sql" in Go?

Tags: postgresql, go, oop

I want to run sql queries like libpq-fe. I have read https://go.dev/src/database/sql/doc.txt, but i can not understand what is the benefit of driver interface.

Sample:

```golang
    connStr := "dbname=postgres replication=database"
    pqConn, err := pq.ConnectDB(connStr)

    pqResult, err := pq.Exec("IDENTIFY_SYSTEM")
    fields, err := pqResult.Fields()
    tuples, err := pgResult.Tuples()

    err := pqConn.SendQuery("BASE_BACKUP")
    pqResult, err := pgConn.GetResult()
```

Is there a package can run PostgreSql queries like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah there's a lot of package for postgreSQL driver, one of the example is

https://github.com/jackc/pgx
https://github.com/lib/pq